# データ保存等 UserDefaultsをつかわない

Tags: swift

CoreDataはどのように使えばいいのでしょうか？

また、保存等はどのようにすればいいのでしょうか。

調べてみたのですが、itemとは何でしょうか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

文脈によってitemは意味が変わります。

CoreDataに関して、これだ！という解説の記事を知らないですが、いくつかの記事を見つつ実践して理解していくのがおすすめです。

https://zenn.dev/tomsan96/articles/e76a1088bcf78d